# How to print a while() loop in PDO

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I have a database table with 4 columns: `Name`, `Comment`, `Star`, `Status`.

I want to display all the records of the table on a single page. Here is my query:

```
$sth = $this->db->prepare("SELECT * FROM comment WHERE status = 1");
$sth->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
$sth->execute();

$reviews = array();

while($row = $sth->fetch()){    
    $reviews->name = $row['name'];
    $reviews->comment = $row['comment'];
    $reviews->star = $row['star'];
}

return $reviews;
```

However, `var_dump($reviews)` displays `array(0) { }`. Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are accessing the array as an object with the `->` operator , use `[]` instead.

```
$reviews = array();

while($row = $sth->fetch()){    
    $reviews[]['name'] = $row['name'];            # <---- Change them like this.
    $reviews[]['comment'] = $row['comment'];
    $reviews[]['star'] = $row['star'];
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this now displays the var_dump correctly! If I want to display each result on a different line, what function/syntax could I use?

Comment: You could use a simple `foreach` to loop through an array. If you want me to write it for you, it will be better if you post the `var_dump` output on your question.

Answer (score 0):

You are defining $reviews as array.

```
$reviews = array();
```

then how can you do this-

```
$reviews->name = $row['name'];
```

this way you do for object not array