# sql associative array with column name as header

Tags: php, mysql, sql, arrays, mysqli

I have a simple table in my database with messages toUser and fromUser.  Right now there is one toUser and 3 fromUser.  I want to organize my result with fromUser containing all the row data something like this:

```
Array(
  user1 => array(array(
    [id] => 1
    [message] => some message from user 1
    ),
    (
    [id] => 1
    [message] => another message from user 1
    )),
  user2 => array(array(
    [id] => 2
    [message] => some message from user 2
    ),
    (
    [id] => 2
    [message] => another message from user 2
    )),
  user3 => array(array(...
```

I know my syntax is probably wrong but I hope you get my point.  I tried using "group by fromName" but that only gave me the last message.  What's the right syntax for a query like this?

```
$query = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT * FROM messages WHERE toName='$to' group by fromName");
$messages = array();
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)) {
    $messages[] = $row; //or
    $messages[$row['fromName']] = $row; //didn't work either
}
print_r($messages);
```

**Edit**: Just found the fricking answer:

```
$query = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT * FROM messages WHERE toName='$to'");
$messages = array();
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)) {
    $messages[$row['fromName']][] = $row;
}
print_r($messages);
```

Guess you just had to make an array from "`$messages[$row['fromName']->[]<-`".

Comment: Just a quick note about `$messages[$row['fromName'] = $row;` it's missing a `]`

Comment: You're right, I just typed that here, forgot the ].  Unfortunately, thats not the problem

Comment: I know, I just thought I'd point it out, in case someone were to post it "as an answer" ;-) Some would have jumped at the chance. ;-)

Comment: Does this guy have a suggestion how to change my query to get the desired result? :)

Comment: Sorry, I suck at arrays; could never wrap my head around those and still can't for the life of me.

Comment: I just got it...what is it about stackoverflow???  I've been looking for the past 2 hours for an answer.  I post the question here and 10 minutes later I find the damn answer.  Not the first time this happened!!!

Comment: Must be something in the air ;-) so what was it? I for one am curious.

Comment: Just added the answer in my post

Comment: I had a sneaking suspicion about it too for some reason. I was about to suggest you see [**this answer**](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22881200/) on SO which looked familiar. I may not be good with arrays, but I am good at remembering patterns.

Comment: **+1** btw, for having figured it out for yourself, cheers.

Comment: I'm learning from my mistakes.  Thanks for the convo haha!

Comment: Anytime! It's the best way to learn too!